# Reading Excel List Value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a Sheet X and for cell C22 i have validated the data with a list , [consider a list having values A,B,C]. I need  to fetch the selected string from the list in the cell and print or Assign in another cell using Vba

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean read the value from C22 and place it in another cell?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes . But only the string value not the validation

Comment: Dim x = (Range(C22).Validation.Formula1) , this is what i am trying

Answer (score 0):

For i = 22 To 30
    Dim MyString As String
    MyString = Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).value
    MsgBox (MyString)

done , Thanks